# Dynamically adding step to mat-stepper and navigating to it throws out of bounds error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper, mat-stepper

I am working with a simple mat-stepper where steps are generated from an array using `*ngFor`.

I'd like to dynamically add a step to the display after the stepper has been rendered and then **immediately navigate to it programmatically**.

Adding the steps dynamically works fine - the navigating part is the issue as it leads to an exception: "Error: cdkStepper: Cannot assign out-of-bounds value to `selectedIndex`" even though the assigned index should be in bounds based on the steps having been passed to the components.

Simplified example to illustrate the issue (the timeout is just a placeholder for async behaviour that leads to the addition of extra steps).

```js
steps = ['step1', 'step2'];
selectedIndex = 1;

ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.steps.push('step3');
    this.selectedIndex = 2;
  });
}
```

```html
<mat-stepper [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
  <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps">
    {{step}}
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

Any ideas on how we might get around this?

Full Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdafd9?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular material stepper add new step items dynamically on every click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274173/angular-material-stepper-add-new-step-items-dynamically-on-every-click)

Comment: @Adam the issue you reference focuses just on adding steps dynamically which works fine - it's the navigating to it immediately afterwards which causes the exception

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the stepper needs a bit to initialize. If you add the step before setTimeout it works just fine.